# how do you get rid of (, comma, and ' that is in print in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Def main():
name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
age = int(raw_input("How old are you?: "))
number = int(raw_input("What is your favorite number?: "))
print name , 'will be 100 years old in the year of', (100 - age + 2017)
main()
```

And it gives me answers without (, comma, and '.

But when I add number *:

```
print number * (name , 'will be 100 years old in the year of', (100 - age + 2017))
```

Then it gives me answer with (, comma, and ' and I don't really see why it's doing that.

Also, If I want that answer to be in different line, for instance,

Python
Python
Python

How can I use \n to separate like that?

Comment: So you do: `print name, "will be something in", other`

Comment: I want to print that statement as many as the user input in what is your favorite number. So if i do print number * name, 'will be 100 years old in the year of', (100 - age + 2017) then i get the same problem by having (, comma, and '. I dont really understand why it's doing it

Answer (score 0):

You're generating `result` as a tuple, and `print` will display that using parentheses and commas to show that it's a tuple. You need to pass it directly to the `print` statement (which can take any number of arguments):

```
print name , 'will be 100 years old in the year of', (100 - age + 2017)
```

In Python 3, you could also unpack it:

```
result = name , 'will be 100 years old in the year of', (100 - age + 2017)
print (*result)
```

Even better (regardless of the Python version) would be to use [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
print '{0} will be 100 years old in the year of {1}'.format(name, 100 - age + 2017)
```

Comment: Unpacking doesn't seem to work as it's a Python 3's feature. It results in a `SyntaxError` in 2.7.

Comment: @ForceBru: The `SyntaxError` comes from trying to use Python 2's `print` statement as a function. After a `from __future__ import print_function`, the unpacking solution works in Python 2.

Comment: I want to print that statement as many as the user input in what is your favorite number. So if i do print number * name, 'will be 100 years old in the year of', (100 - age + 2017) then i get the same problem by having (, comma, and '. I dont really understand why it's doing it

Comment: By doing `number * (...,...,...)` you're creating a tuple again, and a tuple is printed like that. If you want to print something `n` times, use a loop (`for i in range(n): print ...`).